# What is ESB ? What it Does ? Where it runs?

Tags: esb

Can anyone elaborately explain about ESB ? I am new to it. Apart from integrating applications, I need to know where does ESB runs ? what types of services it can be integrated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try google and wiki, once you have a better understanding of Esb, then ask something more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Neill. I am doing what you said. It would be helpful to me, if you say what esb is, from your perspective.

Comment: The question is too broad, and my answer will be to long. First I suggest you read up between hub-spoke federated esb's and distributed esb's.

Comment: Ok. I do that and come back to you soon.  Thanks once again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an ESB and what is it good for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597397/what-is-an-esb-and-what-is-it-good-for)

Answer (score 1):

An enterprise service bus (ESB) is a software architecture concept that enables communication among various applications. Instead of having to make each of your applications communicate directly with each other in all their various formats, each application simply communicates with the ESB, which handles transforming and routing the messages to their appropriate destinations.

An ESB provides its fundamental services through an event-driven and standards-based messaging engine (the bus). Thanks to ESB, integration architects can exploit the value of messaging without writing code. Developers typically implement an ESB using technologies found in a category of middleware infrastructure products, usually based on recognized standards. As with a Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA), an ESB is essentially a collection of enterprise architecture design patterns that is now implemented directly by many enterprise software products.

Moreover, WSO2 ESB is a fast, light-weight, and versatile enterprise service bus. It is 100% open source and released under the Apache License v2.0. Using WSO2 ESB you can perform a variety of enterprise integration patterns, including filtering, transforming, and routing SOAP, binary, plain XML, and text messages that pass through your business systems by HTTP, HTTPS, JMS, mail, etc.

Resources: http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2013/08/10-minute-tutorial-for-extending-wso2.html