# How Mule ESB would be better then Spring/databases?

Tags: database, spring, mule, esb

How Mule ESB would be a better choice as compared to database/Spring? I have learnt mule provides transaction management, Security Manager but Spring also provides the same functionality, then why to another layer Mule ESB where Spring alone can provide these features?

Comment: Hi, if you are asking this question this means you probably lack a bit of knowledge of what is an ESB. This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597397/what-is-an-esb-and-what-is-it-good-for . In short you can't compare them, they have different purposes.

Comment: @MauroRocco  I am beginner in terms of Mule & ESB as well . I have worked on Spring so just wanted to know how Mule could be different to Spring that was the reason I posted this question. I will go through the url provided by you and get better understanding. If you have other url or knowledge in this context please share.

Answer (score 1):

The ESB is a design pattern (http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageBus.html), much like MVC is one. In a heterogenous environment where you have various applications integrated with one another, will require many point-to-point integrations (App A integrates with App B, A with C, B with D and so on....). As the number of such integrations increase, maintenance becomes a big problem. The ESB tries to solve this by introducing the integration layer, so all applications talk only to the ESB, and the ESB manages the connectivity, routing, transformation of messages between applications.

The Spring+database combination is good for the application layer and the database layer, but won't be useful as an integration layer.

Spring does try to solve this problem to some extent by using Spring Integration.